# Having an issue with custom page content not showing in the band tile

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-band

I'm having an issue with bandClient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync its returning true which I assume means everything was successful but when I click on my band tile nothing is displayed.  I left out the tile creation code below, since I believe that works fine as I'm able to send message to it successfully.  Any ideas?

```
private void CreateLeaderboardPageLayout(BandTile tile)
    {
        // create a scrollable vertical panel that will hold 3 text messages
        ScrollFlowPanel panel = new ScrollFlowPanel
        {
            Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102),
            Orientation = FlowPanelOrientation.Vertical
        };

        // add the text block to contain the first message
        panel.Elements.Add(new TextBlock 
        {
            ElementId = (short) TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message1,
            Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102),
            // left, top, right, bottom margins
            Margins = new Margins(15, 0, 15, 0),
            Color = new BandColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
        });

        // add the text block to contain the second message
        panel.Elements.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            ElementId = (short)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message2,
            Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102),
            // left, top, right, bottom margins
            Margins = new Margins (15, 0, 15, 0),
            Color = new BandColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
        });

        // add the text block to contain the third message
        panel.Elements.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            ElementId = (short)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message3,
            Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102),
            // left, top, right, bottom margins
            Margins = new Margins(15, 0, 15, 0),
            Color = new BandColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
        });

        // create the page layout
        var layout = new PageLayout(panel);


        tile.PageLayouts.Add(layout);
    }

    public async Task UpdateLeaderBoard(IBandClient bandClient)
    {
        // create the object containing the page content to be set
        var pageContent = new PageData(MSC_LEADERBOARD_GUID, 0,
            new TextBlockData((Int16) TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message1,
                "This is the text of the first message"),
            new TextBlockData((Int16) TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message2,
                "This is the text of the second message")
            ,
            new TextBlockData((Int16) TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message3,
                "This is the text of the third message")
            );
        var added = await bandClient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(MSC_TILE_GUID, pageContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit of at most one TextBlock / WrappedTextBlock per page having a string with more than 20 characters. Try reducing the number of characters in the page data TextBlock strings and see if that helps.

Comment: I ran into this issue too.  When there was more than 20 chars the text block wouldn't display.  The problem I'm having is that when I click on tile it says there is nothing to report and check back later.  Which is a different issue than the 20 char limit

Comment: When the tile shows the "check back later" message, it means that the tile has no pages of data to display. If the app has tried to add a page of data to the tile, but that "check back later" message is shown, then it means that the Band considered the page data to be invalid and rejected it. Having 2 or more text strings of > 20 characters in the page data is just one example of page data that would be rejected by the Band.

Comment: So the Band will just reject the page without an error?   It does seem that since I limited my textblocks to 20 chars that the page has been showing.  I'm thinking it was so random before because of the different lengths of strings in the leaderboard

Answer (score 0):

If MSC_LEADERBOARD_GUID is a constant, that may be the problem. Each PageData requires a unique Guid. If there's only one page on your tile it shouldn't be a problem but changing it might be worth a try.

Comment: I only have one page and the documentation says that if you reuse the same guid it will update that page instead of creating a new one.